# Can't submit form after redirect in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm writing web app for my school and I'm fighting with one thing for a five days in a row now. It's site where you can do test and get result immediately. And here are two pages available when test is started - Dashboard and test page. I wrote a simple timer in JS which stop and submit a form when reach 00:00.

```
if(t.minutes <= 0 && t.seconds <= 1 && window.location.pathname === "/"){
  clearInterval(timeinterval);
  localStorage.setItem("test", "y");
  window.location.replace("http://ruby-on-rails-139616.nitrousapp.com:3000/student/start?id="+gon.test);
}
else if(t.minutes <= 0 && t.seconds <= 0){
  clearInterval(timeinterval);
  document.getElementById("t").submit();
}
```

As you can see it recognize user location. And there is my problem. I have this code at top of my timer file

```
var l = localStorage.getItem("test");
alert(l);

if(l === "y"){
  localStorage.removeItem("test");
  document.getElementById("t").submit();
} else { //timer code }
```

I can't get form submit. Anyone experienced problem like this?

Comment: any errors in debugger console?

Comment: @EricPhilips Unfortunately not, it seems like everything is fine. It check  l variable, remove it from local storage(checked, this part of code works) and then stop without executing form submit